# Controllers with same name in one area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes

is it possible we have this two path?

I mean Controllers with same name in same area but in different folders?

Controllers > Helper > TestControllr.cs

Controllers > TestFolder > Helper > TestController.cs

Comment: yes it is possible, because both the controllers would having different namespaces but it is not a good practise. You must give proper and appropriate names to controllers.

Comment: Namespace just like container. Try it

Comment: could you please give an example? do I need wrote something in routeconfig.cs? or can I handle it only using @html.action?

Comment: It's bad idea, but it's possible.